# What is CompositeDisposable in RxJava

Tags: android, rx-java

I am an Android Student. I want to learn RxJava. My Question is "What is  CompositeDisposable in RxJava?". Please describe in detail.

Answer (score 90):

Composite disposable makes disposing (think cancelling early) easier.  Say you have an activity that has multiple api calls happening at once:

```
var disposable = api.call1(arg1, arg2).subscribe(...)
var disposable2 = api.call2(arg1).subscribe(...)
var disposable3 = api.call3().subscribe()
```

If you need to prematurely dispose (e.g. the user navigating away from the activity) then you'd need to do this:

```
disposable.dispose()
disposable2.dispose()
disposable3.dispose()
```

If you instead use a CompositeDisposable you can store all of the disposables in it.  Like so:

```
val composite = CompositeDisposable()
composite.add(api.call1(arg1, arg2).subscribe(...))
composite.add(api.call2(arg1).subscribe(...))
composite.add(api.call3().subscribe())
```

And then you can make one dispose call instead:

```
composite.dispose()
```

If you are using kotlin you can use operator overloading to make this look nicer:

```kotlin
operator fun CompositeDisposable.plusAssign(disposable: Disposable) {
    this.add(disposable)
}
```

Which enables you to express it as:

```
val composite = CompositeDisposable()
composite += api.call1(arg1, arg2).subscribe(...)
composite += api.call2(arg1).subscribe(...)
composite += api.call3().subscribe()
```

Disposable signifies a request (think work being done) and has a method called dispose for disposing of the request.

Comment: What is Disposable ?

Comment: What's the difference between this and storing disposables in a list?

Comment: Not much, other than you can call dispose on the CompositeDisposable without having to iterate through all the items in your list.

Comment: This is great! So I can dispose all subscription in just one call like `composite.dispose()` after I added each `Observable` or `Single`?

Answer (score 12):

CompositeDisposable is just a class to keep all your disposables in the same place to you can dispose all of then at once. Like:

```
Disposable disposable1;
Disposable disposable2;
Disposable disposable3;

CompositeDisposable composite = new CompositeDisposable();
composite.addAll(disposable1, disposable2, disposable3)
composite.dispose()
```

All of then are disposed

Comment: What is Disposable

Comment: It is an interface for a class that can be disposed. Observable, Single, Completable and Maybe all implements this interface. It is important to dispose your observables to avoid memory leaks

Comment: What is difference between CompositeDisposable vs SerialDisposable

Comment: @praveen2034 `compositeDisposable` contains list of disposables, while `SerialDisposable` is a one disposable, that can be replaced or updated with new disposable. More details about the difference are here: https://rb.gy/9vir4y

Answer (score 11):

`CompositeDisposable` is a convenient class for bundling up multiple `Disposable`s, so that you can dispose them all with one method call on `CompositeDisposable`.

You can add disposables to a `CompositeDisposable` with `CompositeDisposable#add`

Instead of calling `dispose()` on each `Disposable` individually, you call `CompositeDisposable#clear()` to dispose all `Disposable`s that have been added. If you want to dispose all current `Disposable`s **and** automatically dispose any `Disposable`s that are added in the future, call `CompositeDisposable#dispose()`. It kind of makes sense, you are literally disposing the `CompositeDisposable` when you call `dispose()` on it, so it makes sense that any `Disposable`s you add are disposed.

Answer (score 0):

Adding to the above CompositeDisposable offers consistent time space complexity of O(n) irrespective of the addition and removal of multiple disposables, which is also cleared when activity or fragment is destroyed.